# QGIS 2.0 Plug Repository Connection Failed

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I'm trying to connect to the QGIS Official Plugin Repository but the status within the Plugin Manager window is always"unavailable" for the URL - http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml.

I'm running QGIS 2.0 within Windows 7.

Could the problem be that QGIS is unable to detect the proxy settings used on the corporate network?

Comment: Did you try to set the proxy settings in the Options?

Comment: I could do but how would I find out the proxy settings within the Windows 7 environment? I doubt our IT will give out such information without a massive inquiry into why I need such information.

Comment: You can also download the plugin zip files manually and unzip them into the plugin folder. You could check your internet browser settings for proxy infromation.

Comment: tanks. solved. I've been changed the proxy options on the settings..